# Update from 15.10 to 16.04 - Can't get past loading screen

Tags: 16.04, updates, dell, xps

Recently upgraded ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04 and I can't get past the purple ubuntu loading screen. After awhile I end up with a black screen and I can't continue from here.

There is not much of a verbose output of any logs or anything I can see but one is: `*ERROR* 5.4 Gbps link rate without HBR2/TPS3 support`

I tried booting up with a live CD with ubuntu 14.04 on and it works fine.

Comment: What are your PC Specs?

Comment: Its a dell XPS 13 2015 edition with intel HD graphics.

Comment: I've just been reading on your error message, do you connect your laptop to an external display?

Comment: Hey Tony, No I don't use external display. I tried with a hdmi cabel though but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold your left shift pushed down when GRUB starts (right after the BIOS boot), you should get some boot options. Normally there is a safe mode that might help you out. At least you will get the full boot messages whatever option you choose.

If you have not, please do not forget to make a backup of your data (you can boot your live CD for that).

See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/#162078) for a complete recipe for black screen problem solving.